# What is the meaning of "stock" dilution on the Massive Dev Chart website?

Tags: film, terminology, developing, developer

I'm looking at the [Massive Dev Chart website](https://www.digitaltruth.com/devchart.php?Film=%25Ilford%20HP5%25&Developer=%25D-76%25&mdc=Search&TempUnits=C&TimeUnits=D). It shows a table like this:

[image]

What's the meaning of `stock` dilution there? How should we prepare the developer on that condition?

Comment: Seeing this on the "Hot Network Questions" list, I thought it was about dilution of stock investments that happens e.g. in companies offering generous stock options, and only then I noticed the photography logo...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jargon of photographic chemical mixing and preparation:

- Concentrate — Chemical that comes bottled in kits and must be diluted.
- Stock Solution — A chemical that has been mixed from concentrates or powdered formula. This solution must be diluted with water for use.
- Working Solution — Photo chemicals at the correct concentration for use.

As a rule of thumb — concentrates and stock solutions have prolonged shelf life. A working solution has greatly reduced shelf life.

Answer (score 8):

'Stock' means 1+0: don't dilute the dev at all, just use the stock solution you made up.

Comment: So glad it doesn't require boiling chicken bones.

Comment: @xiota: surely you always add chicken bones to your dev?  Vastly improves the results I find.  In fact I'm experimenting with leaving out the dev altogether and just using boiled pig trotters...

Comment: Now I remember why I use digital...

Comment: @tfb thanks. If so how do you control the temperature with stock? And the development time mentioned in the table, does it include agitation time?

Comment: @neversaint When I developed B&W film, I measured the solution temperature, then looked up the development time in a [chart](https://www.digitaltruth.com/devchart.php?doc=timetemp) adjusted for temperature.

Comment: @xiota I'll let you in on a little secret. The absolute *best* negatives come from adding a bit of home-made pork broth to your caffenol. Do make sure that the bones were previously smoked with apple wood before making your stock solution.

Comment: @neversaint how to control for temperature would make a great next question!

Comment: @neversaint If your stock chemicals are not at the temp you need you can place them in a water bath to raise or lower the temp accordingly.  If you want to raise the temp of the stock solution then get a container that is larger then the one the stock solution is in and fill it with HOT water, place the sealed container that the stock solution is in  into the water, Now you have sealed bottle of stock solution floating a **hot water bath**.  Check the temp of the stock solution every so often to monitor its rise in temp. Smaller amounts will warm up quicker.  **Ice bath** to lower temps.